# What happens to my app store reviews if I remove my app from sale?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm thinking of removing my app from sale on iOS App store, but am afraid of losing my reviews. If I restore the app later will I get the reviews back? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about functionality of the App Store and not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get your review back after again app is "ready for sale" If you remove your app from "ready for sale" in account then only disappear app from app store until app is ready for sale again.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, reviews are not deleted unless you remove the complete application. So removing it from sales can be a temporary process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting application - then all your reviews will get deleted. But, if you are removing your app from sale, then your reviews will remain as it is.